# Acces parent record from an embedded object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to access to the parent object of an embedded model object ? For example :

```js
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    emails : DS.hasMany('App.Email', { embedded: true })
});

App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
    label : DS.attr('string'),
    email : DS.attr('string'),

    setParentUpdated: function() {
         if(this.get('isDirty') == true) 
            // this.get('parent').get('stateManager').goToState('updated');
            // I would like to do something like this.get('parent')
            // to access 'App.Person' instance object
    }.observes('isDirty')
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply setup a `belongsTo` relation?

```
App.Email = DS.Model.extend({
  person: DS.belongsTo('App.Person')

  //...
});
```

Then you will be able to use the `person` property of the email.

Comment: Thanks mike! But I can't because 'App.Email' is not only embedded on 'App.Person' but also on some other models.

Comment: It should not be an issue, as the relation will be lazy, so loaded only when dereferenced. If not, nothing will occur, leaving the behavior as it is for now.

Comment: @Thomas you should be able to define multiple belongsTo relationships on a model.